# lib.so in android app and readable stacktrace in Crashlytics

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have compiled external C++ library in my project. Unfortunately, this library is crashing from time to time and stack trace in Crashlyics isn't readable.
How to display readable stack trace for C++ external lib in Crashlytics?

Comment: If your app is registered on Google Play Store, you may find crash logs in the dev. dashboard. Sometimes, they give more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the steps here for uploading these symbols: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#uploading-symbols-for-external-dependencies

Thanks!